# Do something if AngularJS $location.path() changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I have a navigation menu with links to different sections. This navigation bar is a list which is only displayed by clicking on the button 'menu'. I would like that on load of the new section this list is not displayed.

Therefore I thought I could use [`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to detect any change on the url and if so remove the class.

The idea is:

```
if($location.path() CHANGES){
    document.querySelector('[data-navigation]').classList.remove('open-status');
}
```

How do you make a conditional statement using `$location` to trigger an action when the url changes.

P.D. The url at this moment works with an hashtag. So it would be: www.whatever.com/#about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I used a combination of both answers, this is the outcome that worked for me:

```
scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
    DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess you probably meant using [$routeChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route), something like,

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
     //location changed
     //do something here            
});
```

Comment: there is also a `$routeChangeStart`, `$locationChangeSuccess`, `$locationChangeStart` that could be used depending on situation

Comment: @maurycy What are the main differences? I already had injected $location so I will try it out with your answer.